# how to show and hide loading img in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a registration form below, all i want to implement is show a loading image when a user clicks the button and to hide when form is submitted.

```
<script>
    angular.module('AngularJSLoginReg', [])
    .controller('AngularLoginRegController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        this.regForm = function() {

            var user_data='user_username=' +this.inputData.username+'&user_password='+this.inputData.password+'&user_role='+this.inputData.role;


            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'regiter.php',
                data: user_data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

                if ( data.trim() === 'success') {
                    $scope.successMsg = "Signup Successful";



                } else {
                    $scope.errorMsg = "Problem with Data";
                }

            })


        }



    }]);
    </script>
```

I have tried

```
$("#loading").show();
$("#loading").hide();
```

at html i have added but cannot get it to work

```
<span id="loading">Loading Please wait...</span>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"> Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable in $scope and use ng-show to show or hide it .

```html
<span id="loading" ng-show="loaders.register">Loading Please wait...</span>

<script>
angular.module('AngularJSLoginReg', [])
.controller('AngularLoginRegController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.loader = {
   "register":false // by default false
   // you can declare more here if there are some more loaders in the page
 }
 this.regForm = function() {
  var user_data='user_username=' +this.inputData.username+'&user_password='+this.inputData.password+'&user_role='+this.inputData.role;
  $scope.loader.register=true; // show loader on start of call
  $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'regiter.php',
   data: user_data,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .success(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   if ( data.trim() === 'success') {
    $scope.successMsg = "Signup Successful";
    }
   else {
    $scope.errorMsg = "Problem with Data";
   }
   $scope.loader.register=false;   // hide when Response comes
  })
 }
}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show loader.

```
<span id="loading" ng-show="loading">Loading Please wait...</span>


angular.module('AngularJSLoginReg', [])
    .controller('AngularLoginRegController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        this.regForm = function () {
            $scope.loading = true;
            var user_data = 'user_username=' + this.inputData.username + '&user_password=' + this.inputData.password + '&user_role=' + this.inputData.role;
            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'regiter.php',
                    data: user_data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    if (data.trim() === 'success') {
                        $scope.successMsg = "Signup Successful";
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorMsg = "Problem with Data";
                    }
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    $scope.loading = false;
                })
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: It is better to place `$scope.loading = false;` into `finally` section.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy if you want to have a loading by `$scope` just run it after user clicked and then let it decisions when loading end.

```
$scope.save = function(){
     $scope.loading = true;
     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'regiter.php',
            data: user_data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
           if ( data.trim() === 'success') {
              //do somthing
           }else{
              //do somthing
           }

           //always it's false 
           $scope.loading = false;
        }, function(error){
           //on error
           $scope.loading = false;
        })
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<div ng-if="loading"><img alt="loading" src="loading.gif"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can should create a flag which tells whether the http request has finished.
For demonstration purposes I use `$timeout` instead a real http request.

e.g.

```
this.submittedFinished = false;
  this.submit = (myForm) => {
    $timeout(() => {
      this.submittedFinished = true;
      myForm.$setPristine();
      this.someInput = null;
    }, 1000);
```

Then in the view you can use [form  controller api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and configure your css. It could be something like this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="app.submit(myForm)" ng-class="{'finished':app.submittedFinished}" novalidate>
    <label for="someInput">Some Input</label>
    <input ng-model="app.someInput" name="someInput" type="text" id="someInput" required>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    <img ng-show="myForm.$submitted && !app.submittedFinished" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif">
  </form>
```

And css:

```
form {
  position: relative;
}

form.ng-submitted input,
form.ng-submitted button {
  display: none;
}

form.ng-submitted.finished input,
form.ng-submitted.finished button {
    display: block;
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ou74f9Ly/1/)